# Solving system of three linear equations with four variables and one parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'd like to discuss number of solutions based on value of parameter $a$.

$\begin{cases} (a+3)x-4y+2z+2t=a+1\\
2x-2y-z+t=a \\
x-2y+z+(a+1)t=a
\end{cases}$

Some guidance on how to count rank here would be benficial. I tried to use Gauss elimination method, but I didn't manage to make a staircase-like pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The criterion for solutions to exist is that the matrix of the system and the augmented matrix have the same rank. When this condition is satisfied, the rank is the codimension of the affine space of solutions.

Here, one can conclude without performing a full RREF:
\begin{align}
&\left[\!\!
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
a+3&-4&2&2&a+1 \\
2&-2&-1&1& a \\
1&-2&1&a+1&a
\end{array}
\!\!\right]\rightsquigarrow
\left[\!\!
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&-2&1&a+1&a\\
2&-2&-1&1& a \\
a+3&-4&2&2&a+1 
\end{array}
\!\!\right]\rightsquigarrow \\[1ex]
&\left[\!\!
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&-2&1&a+1&a\\
0&2&-3& -2a-1 &-a \\
0&2(a+1)&-a-1&-a^2-4a-1&-a^2-2a+1 
\end{array}
\!\!\right]\rightsquigarrow \\[1ex]
&\left[\!\!
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&-2 & 1 & a+1 & a\\
0 & 2 & -3 & 1 & -2a-1 \\
0&0&2(a+1) & a^2-a & 1-a  
\end{array}
\!\!\right]
\end{align}
and clearly, both matrices have rank $3$.

Comment: Could you explain how did you obtain third matrix from the second one?
The first transition is simply - just swapping first and third row. What have you done next? Did you multiply first row by -2 and add to second and multiply first row by -(a+3) and add to third?

Comment: I've managed to do such REF: https://goo.gl/kNf14f Could you check your calculations and mine?

I think you didn't provide RREF, but REF. Am I right? RREF should have ones just after zeros on every row?

Comment: Your computation is fine. I had 3 errors. For my excuse, I made the computations directly on scree, and I see now that at some points,  I messed the 1st and  3rd rows for row operations. It's (supposedly)  fixed now.  Thanks for pointing the problem!

Comment: It's ok. Now it looks like we have same REF.
Now, if rank of A and rank of U (augmented A) is equal to 3, does it mean (using K-C theorem) that we have infinitely many solutions no matter what value of *a* parameter is?

Comment: Yes, in such a case, the set of solutions is an affine line (codimension $3$ in $\mathbf R^4$).